# docker-credential-desktop.exe not installed

Tags: docker, linux

Moving from `Docker Desktop for Windows` to `Docker Server / CLI for Linux` to escape the license fee, I used the [standard documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) for Ubuntu to install docker into my `WSL2`.

After frankensteining it that way, `docker` itself seemed to run okay, but `docker-compose` was broken.

```
user@COMPUTER:~/git/project/rest_backend$ docker-compose up --build 
Pulling postgres (gitlab-int.company.de/team/dependency_proxy/containers/postgres:latest)...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 72, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 128, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1077, in up
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1073, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 548, in up
  File "compose/service.py", line 361, in ensure_image_exists
  File "compose/service.py", line 1250, in pull
  File "compose/progress_stream.py", line 102, in get_digest_from_pull
  File "compose/service.py", line 1215, in _do_pull
  File "site-packages/docker/api/image.py", line 396, in pull
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 48, in get_config_header
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 324, in resolve_authconfig
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 235, in resolve_authconfig
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 262, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 287, in _get_store_instance
  File "site-packages/docker/credentials/store.py", line 25, in __init__
docker.credentials.errors.InitializationError: docker-credential-desktop.exe not installed or not available in PATH
[323] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

When you uninstall `Docker Desktop for Windows`, you lose all `exe` files - including `docker-credential-desktop.exe`. But you still need a credentials-store for the `docker login` part.

As written in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store) there are several alternatives.

I found, that `pass` works. The D-BUS plugin seems to be easier to configure, but apparently requires a graphical interface.

So download `docker-credential-pass-vx.y.z-amd64.tar.gz` from the [Docker's git repo](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/releases), extract it (`tar xvf <file>`), put it in your path like `sudo mv docker-credential-pass /usr/local/bin/`, make sure it is executable (`chmod a+x docker-credential-pass`) and test it with `docker-credential-pass list`. It requires you to have a configured [instance](https://www.passwordstore.org/) of `pass` - test with `pass list`.

Then check the docker-config at `$HOME/.docker/config.json` to make sure it uses `pass`:

```
  "credsStore": "pass"
```

That made my escape from the license-fee complete.

Comment: thank you man! I was struggling with this problem